# How to configure Entity facade to disable checking entity existence in Moqui framework

Tags: java, groovy, moqui

According to Moqui documentation, Based on Data-Base Metadata section, The first time (in each run of Moqui) the Entity Facade does a database operation on an entity it will check to see if the table for that entity exists (unless configured not to). My question is How to configure Moqui to disable entity existence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On moqui-conf.entity-facade.datasource there is startup-add-missing attribute that takes the value from default-property 'entity_add_missing_startup'. So in short add this entry on MoquiDevConf.xml and MoquiProductionConf.xml:

```
<default-property name="entity_add_missing_startup" value="false"/>
```